# Install 2 versions of the same chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to install the same chrome extension twice on the same chrome browser?

In this case, I want to install [Video Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk?hl=en) twice so I can have 2 different lists of videos that are blocked and be able to choose which set of videos to allow on Youtube.

Comment: I don't think that is possible as each extension has its own unique ID.

Answer (score 5):

I was wanting to do this on google translator. And it is possible!
It worked for me and I will share the result. I already did some extensions and I know the way a little.

1. Go to chrome://extensions/
2. Search for your extension
3. Find her code (it's always a bunch of letters, for example, google translator's is "aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb")
4. Now you will find the extension folder, go to chrome://version/

4.1 Search for "Profile Path" (Example: there will be something like "C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ProfileX")

4.2 Open this folder and look for a folder named "Extensions" (Example: it will have something like "C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ProfileX\Extensions")

5. Now find the extension code you want to duplicate (in my case it was "aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb")
6. Open the extension folder, and open the folders until you find a file named "manifest.json", it's not hard to find it (in my case I found it here: C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ProfileX\Extensions\aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb\2.0.7_1\manifest.json)
7. You have to copy the folder where this file is (in my case I copied the folder "2.0.7_1")

7.1 And paste in a different place, you can rename this folder.

8. Now we have to change some values, open "manifest.json"

8.1 We have to delete a property called "key", it has the following pattern:

```
"key": "blablabla ...",
```

*OBS: Sometimes it does not have a comma at the end, if right after the last quote there is no comma, delete from the first quote to the last quote of this pattern.
If you have the comma (most common), delete from the first quote to the last comma in this pattern.*

9. Save the file
10. Now let's put the extension. Go to chrome://extensions/ again

10.1 Enable Developer mode by ticking the checkbox in the upper-right corner.

10.2 Click "load unpacked" and look for the folder from step 7.1, then open it.

And that's it!

What you have done is literally copy an extension and run it in developer mode. The bad implication is that this is not synchronized between computers, and this extension you copied will no longer update, you would have to do the same procedure again to update the extension. And sometimes there are some problems with the extension too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question also imply user can choose which version to run, which is not sure possible with your solution.

Comment: He can still use "Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)" to enable or disable the extension he wants to keep in use (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc)

Comment: I even finished testing copies of this extension with simple word lists by turning each one on and off individually with "Extensions Manager", when activating both extensions at the same time gives some kind of conflict, but it worked very well with each one being activated at different times, I think is due to the type of extension.